# A horizontal chart with Ordinal scale yscale, but instead of pure flat names > a tree structure<

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am in the middle of a project. The project include   the design of a marketing dashboard using javascript and the amazing d3.js.
I need a horizontal chart with Ordinal scale, but instead of pure flat name I have a tree structure.
So instead of text I am design a tree for  the vertical labels... 
Requirement : When the end user click on one the node all the corresponded bar(s) collapse to one bar (off course the value of this bar is the sum of the children bars.)  In order to be a histogram, all the bars must start from the same x. Also the distance from bar to bar, in the vertical direction, should be the same.

The following “toy” program shows the above vertical label out .  Unfortunately in order to achieve the desirable layout I have added “dummy node” .  This is not a solution because I cannot figure out, how to make the “node collapse function”. 
Thank you for your time.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<style>
 .node {
        font: 11px sans-serif; 
       }

 .link {
        fill: none;
       stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1px;
       }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<div id="viz"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">


  var treeData = { "name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0] , "children" :  [
                 { "name" : "Super Specials", "c":[150, 5, 4,10], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }      ]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Package Deals", "c":[50, 15, 4,20], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Audio & Home Theatre", "c":[120, 15, 4,10] , "children" :  [
                   { "name" : "Speaker Packs", "c":[45, 15, 5,23], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }  
                   ,{ "name" : "Portable Radios", "c":[40, 15, 7,26], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                       ,{ "name" : "Amplifiers", "c":[51, 15, 4,26], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                   ,{ "name" : "Accessories", "c":[53, 15, 9,24], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                       ,{ "name" : "Home Theatre Systems", "c":[54, 15, 3,26], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                       ,{ "name" : "Hi-Fi Systems", "c":[56, 15, 4,27], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                        ]}
                    ,{ "name" : "Televisions & Videos", "c":[130, 55, 8,10] , "children" :  [
                   { "name" : "Televisions", "c":[51, 15, 4,26], "children" :  [
                       { "name" : "LED", "c":[45, 15, 5,23]}
                           ,{ "name" : "Plasma", "c":[40, 15, 7,26]}
                           ,{ "name" : "LCD", "c":[51, 15, 4,26]}

                       ]}
                       ,{ "name" : "Players & Recorders", "c":[45, 15, 5,23] , "children" :  [
                           { "name" : "Dvd Players & Recorders", "c":[45, 15, 5,23]}
                           ,{ "name" : "Blu-Ray Players and Recorders", "c":[40, 15, 7,26]}                
                           ]}
                       ,{ "name" : "Set Top Boxes & PVR", "c":[40, 15, 7,26], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                       ,{ "name" : "Accessories", "c":[53, 15, 9,24], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }

                    ]}
                    ,{ "name" : "Computers & Technology", "c":[140, 66, 4,4], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                    ,{ "name" : "Whitegoods", "c":[120, 35, 4,7], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                    ,{ "name" : "Furniture", "c":[50, 25, 12,9], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                    ,{ "name" : "Cooking", "c":[80, 25, 4,4], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                    ,{ "name" : "Heating & Cooling", "c":[87, 43, 2,22], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                    ,{ "name" : "Floor Care", "c":[78, 15, 4,12], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                    ,{ "name" : "Small Appliances", "c":[78, 17, 14,3], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                    ,{ "name" : "Personal Grooming", "c":[45, 9, 4,5], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "DIY Security", "c":[47, 5, 9,0], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                    ,{ "name" : "Gadgets", "c":[23, 57, 4,0], "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
            ]};


  //
         var vis = d3.select("#viz").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 800)
        .attr("height", 800)
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(100, 0)");

      var labelx=770;
      var labely=650;
     var tree = d3.layout.tree()
           .size([labelx,labely]) .separation(function(a, b) { return 1  });



     //http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

     var nodes = tree.nodes(treeData);


     var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { 

                var retx,rety;

                retx=d.y;
                rety=d.x;
                if(d.children==null)
                {
                    //retx=labely;
                }
                   return [retx, rety]; 
             }
             );





      var link = vis.selectAll("pathlink")
        .data(tree.links(nodes))
        .enter().append("svg:path")
       .style("opacity",  function(d) { 
                    var ret=1;
                    if(d.source.depth==0)
                    {
                        ret=0;
                    }
                return ret;
           })
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", diagonal);



       var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })


     var rec = vis.selectAll("g.node")   
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:g")





       node.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r",  function(d) { 
            var ret=4.5;
            if(d.name===" ")
            {
                ret=0.01;
            }
            return ret;
            });


       var txtw=node.append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(-8,0)"; });

       var text=txtw.append("svg:text")
        .attr("dx", function(d) {
            var ret=0;
            if(d.children === undefined)
            {
                ret=16;
            } 
            return  ret;})
        .attr("dy", 3)
        //.attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "end"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

        var maxwith=0
        text.each(function() {
            var tmp=this.getBBox().width;
            if(maxwith<tmp)
            {
                maxwith=tmp;
            }
               });
              console.log("maxwith=",maxwith);



      </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved it. If any one need it, just look the code.
In the place of the green circle I will put the histograms bars.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>

<style>


.node circle {

  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font-size: 11px;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}


 .text_small { font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 11px; }
 .text_big { font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 16px; }

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
/*
 *  to be remnoved after merge with test19.html
 */
/*
 * style for the close,minimize buttoms  start
 */
        .icon {   color:white;  
                  stroke-width:2;
                  fill:white;
                  stroke:gray; }

        .icon_disable{color:white;  
                  stroke-width:2;
                  fill:white;
                  stroke:LightGray ; }
    /*
     *        .buttomcreate{transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
     */
       .buttomcreate{transform: scale(1, 1);
                    position: relative;}


       .buttomdel {transform: scale(0.0, 0.0);
                  transition:  0.5s;
                  position: absolute;}

        .buttoms {position: absolute;
                      top: 0px;
                     left: 0px;}
/*
 * style for the close,minimize buttoms  end
 * 
 *       display: table-cell;   
 */

   #zoom{
/*
    position:fixed;
*/
         }

   #master{position:static


   }

    .hist_test{
         transform: scale(1, 1);
         transition:  0.5s;
         position: relative;
         background-color:grey;   

    }
    .tooltip{           color:black;  
             background-color:white;
                   box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px; 
                       padding-top:7px;
                       padding-bottom:7px;
                       padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;
                       border:1px solid;
                       border-radius:9px;
                       opacity:0.95;
                       }

     .menu{            color:black;  
             background-color:white;
                   box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px; 
                       padding-top:4px;
                       padding-bottom:4px;
                       border:1px solid;

                       }
      .menu2{            color:black;  
             background-color:white;
                       padding-top:2px;
                       padding-bottom:2px;
                       padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;
                  }
      .menu2up{         color:white;  
             background-color:orange;
                padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;
                      padding-top:2px;
                       padding-bottom:2px;
                       padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;
                  }


        .selec{
                      opacity:0.5;             
               }

        .icon {   color:white;  
                  stroke-width:2;
                  fill:white;
                  stroke:black;                              
               }




    .axis path,
    .axis line { fill: none; stroke: black;  shape-rendering: crispEdges; stroke-width:1;}
    .axis text { font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 16px; }



    .axis_names path,
    .axis_names line { fill: none; stroke: black;  shape-rendering: crispEdges; stroke-width:1;}
    .axis_names text { font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 11px; }
    .axis_name_text_small { font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 11px; }


    .axis_nameb path,
    .axis_nameb line { fill: none; stroke: black;  shape-rendering: crispEdges; stroke-width:1;}
    .axis_nameb text { font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 16px; }
    .axis_name_text_big { font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 16px; }





    .axis_max path,
    .axis_max line { fill: none; stroke: black;  shape-rendering: crispEdges; stroke-width:1;}
    .axis_max text { font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 25.9px; }

    .hist_title {fill: black; font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 20px}
    .hist_xaxis {fill: black; font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 16px}
    .hist_yaxis {fill: black; font-family: sans-serif;  font-size: 16px}
    .hist_green{fill:green}
    .hist_red{fill:red}
    .hist_yellow{fill:yellow}
    .hist_blue{fill:blue}
    .hist_tran{opacity:0.5}


    .options{        
                   box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 5px #888;

                   padding-bottom:7px;
                   padding-right:10px;}

            .iconb {   float:right;
                   }


</style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="viz"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

//  bug There is  a bug in the getBBox  width. "Blu-Ray Players and Recorders" returns a letter smaller width for 11px san-serif




 // to be remnoved after merge with test19.html
 var hist_div = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("id","master") ;
 var small=0;


 //   

 var datasetpp = { "name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0] , "children" :  [
                 { "name" : "Super Specials", "c":[150, 5, 4,10]}
                 //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Package Deals", "c":[50, 15, 4,20]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Audio & Home Theatre", "c":[120, 15, 4,10] , "children" :  [
                   { "name" : "Speaker Packs", "c":[45, 15, 5,23]}
                   //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                   ,{ "name" : "Portable Radios", "c":[40, 15, 7,26]}
                   //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                   ,{ "name" : "Amplifiers", "c":[51, 15, 4,26]}
                   //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                   ,{ "name" : "Accessories", "c":[53, 15, 9,24]}
                   //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                   ,{ "name" : "Home Theatre Systems", "c":[54, 15, 3,26]}
                   //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                   ,{ "name" : "Hi-Fi Systems", "c":[56, 15, 4,27]}
                   //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                    ]}
                ,{ "name" : "Televisions & Videos", "c":[130, 55, 8,10] , "children" :  [
                   { "name" : "Televisions", "c":[51, 15, 4,26], "children" :  [
                       { "name" : "Plasma", "c":[45, 15, 5,23] }
                       ,{ "name" : "LED", "c":[40, 15, 7,26]}
                       ,{ "name" : "LCD", "c":[51, 15, 4,26]}

                       ]}
                   ,{ "name" : "Players & Recorders", "c":[45, 15, 5,23] , "children" :  [
                       { "name" : "Dvd Players & Recorders", "c":[45, 15, 5,23]}
                       ,{ "name" : "Blu-Ray Players and Recorders", "c":[40, 15, 7,26]}                
                       ]}
                   ,{ "name" : "Set Top Boxes & PVR", "c":[40, 15, 7,26]}
                   //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }
                   ,{ "name" : "Accessories", "c":[53, 15, 9,24]}
                   //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]           }

                    ]}
                ,{ "name" : "Computers & Technology", "c":[140, 66, 4,4]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Whitegoods", "c":[120, 35, 4,7]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Furniture", "c":[50, 25, 12,9]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Cooking", "c":[80, 25, 4,4]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Heating & Cooling", "c":[87, 43, 2,22]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Floor Care", "c":[78, 15, 4,12]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Small Appliances", "c":[78, 17, 14,3]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Personal Grooming", "c":[45, 9, 4,5]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "DIY Security", "c":[47, 5, 9,0]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
                ,{ "name" : "Gadgets", "c":[23, 57, 4,0]}
                //, "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]  , "children" : [ {"name" : " ", "c":[150, 5, 4,0]                       }]                     }]}
            ]};


    //global
var tick_witdh=40;  
var text_move=10;
var m = [20, 120, 20, 120],
    w = 1280 - m[1] - m[3],
    h = 800 - m[0] - m[2],
    i = 0;

   var w_start=0; 

  datasetpp.x0 = h / 2;
  datasetpp.y0 = 0;

  //var sizeww=datasetpp.length;

      var vis = d3.select("#viz").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 900)
        .attr("height", 1200)
        //.append("svg:g");
        //.attr("transform", "translate(100, 0)");

      var labelx=1;
      var labely=1;
      var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([labelx,labely]) ;
    //  .separation(function(a, b) { return 1  });
        /*
      var labelx=870;
      var labely=850;
      var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([labelx,labely]) ;
*/

     //http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

      var nodes = tree.nodes(datasetpp);


      var maxdepth=0;    

      var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { 
                return [d.y, d.x]; 
             });

            //       console.log("diagonal=",diagonal);

   //=======================
    function toggleAll(d) 
    {
        if (d.children && d.depth>0) 
        {
            d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
            toggle(d);
        }

    }
   // Toggle children.
    function toggle(d) 
    {
        if (d.children) 
        {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } 
        else 
        {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
    }         
    //==================
    function number_of_leaf(nodes)
    {
        var ret=0;
        //
        // for debug
        //

        if(nodes.children!= null) 
        {
            nodes.children.forEach(function(d)
                         {
                                 ret=number_of_leaf(d)+ret;
                           })
        }
        else
        {
            ret=1;
        }


        return ret;
    }
     /*
          var maxdepth=0;    
         nodes.forEach(function(d)
                               {
                                 if(d.depth>maxdepth)    
                                 {
                                    maxdepth=d.depth;
                                 }      
                               })
    */



   //--------------------------------------------------------------
   function update(source) 
   {
        //var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;
        var duration = 1000; 
        var i_step=0;
        var step_width=labely/number_of_leaf(datasetpp);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
        var nodes = tree.nodes(datasetpp).reverse();
         maxdepth=0;    
         nodes.forEach(function(d)
                               {
                                 if(d.depth>maxdepth)    
                                 {
                                    maxdepth=d.depth;
                                 }      
                               })
   //====================================================================
   //
   //
   //
   //=====================================================================
       var i_depth;
       var catigories_max_label_width=new Array(maxdepth+1);
       var catigories_max_label_height=0;
       var current_label_width;
       var current_label_height;
       var max_label_height=0;
       for(i_depth=0;i_depth<maxdepth+1;i_depth++)
       {
         catigories_max_label_width[i_depth]=0;  //catigories[i_depth,i_cat]  
       }
       var w=window.innerWidth;
       var h=window.innerHeight;
       var svg_test=hist_div.append("svg").attr("width",  w).attr("height", h);

       nodes.forEach(function(d)
            {
                   var i_depth=d.depth;
                   var text_test;

                   if(small===0)
                   {
                        text_test = svg_test.append('text').attr('class', 'text_small')
                                .text(d.name)
                   }                
                   else
                   {
                       text_test = svg_test.append('text').attr('class', 'text_big')
                                .text(d.name)
                    }


                   //catigories_max_label_width[i_depth,i_cat]  
                   text_test.each(function() {
                        var tmpbox=this.getBBox();
                        current_label_width=tmpbox.width;
                        if(current_label_width>catigories_max_label_width[i_depth])
                        {
                            catigories_max_label_width[i_depth]=current_label_width;
                        }
                     //
                        current_label_height=tmpbox.height;
                        if(current_label_height>catigories_max_label_height)
                        {
                            catigories_max_label_height=current_label_height;
                        }                     
                  });
            });
         catigories_max_label_height=catigories_max_label_height*1.6;
         w_start=0; 
         for(i_depth=0;i_depth<maxdepth+1;i_depth++)
         {
            w_start=w_start+catigories_max_label_width[i_depth]+text_move;  //catigories[i_depth,i_cat]  
         }
         w_start=tick_witdh+w_start;
         svg_test.remove();
   //====================================================================
   //
   //
   //
   //=====================================================================

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
        nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
            //
            var numf=number_of_leaf(d);
            if(numf===1)
            {
                i_step++;
                d.x=i_step*catigories_max_label_height;
            }
            else
            {
                d.x=i_step*catigories_max_label_height-(numf-1)*catigories_max_label_height/2;
            }

            var rt=d.name;
    //  d.y = (d.depth)* 180; 
        //  d.y =catigories_max_label_width[d.depth];
            var i_depth;
            var sum=0;
            for(i_depth=0;i_depth<d.depth+1;i_depth++)
            {
                    sum=catigories_max_label_width[i_depth]+sum+text_move;
            }
            d.y =sum;

            //
         });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

 var node_hist = vis.selectAll(".hist")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        var ret="translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; 
        return ret;
        })
      .on("click", function(d) { 
        toggle(d);
         update(d);
          });


    var nodeEnter_hist = node_hist.enter().append("circle") 
      .attr("class", function(d,i) { 
                    var ret="hist";
                    if(d.children!= null)
                    {
                        ret="temporary";
                    }                   
                    return ret;
            }) 
       .attr("r", 5) /* function(d,i) { 
                    var ret=5;
                    if(d.children!= null)
                    {
                        ret=1e-6;
                    }                   
                    return ret;
            }) */
      .attr("cx",function(d) { 
                    return source.y0;//w_start;
                  })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { 
                    return  source.x0;
            })
       .attr("fill","green")

    vis.selectAll(".temporary").remove();

    nodeEnter_hist.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("cx",function(d) { 
                    return w_start;
                  })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { 
                    return  d.x;
            })





  nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
      .style("cursor", function(d) {
                var ret="default";
                if(d.children != null )                 
                {
                    ret="pointer";
                }
            return ret;
         });

  if(small===0)
    {
  nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
        return -text_move;
      //    return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; 
        })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
         return "end";
        //return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; 
        })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
       .style("font-size", "11px")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
     }
     else
     {
          nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
        return -text_move;
      //    return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; 
        })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
         return "end";
        //return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; 
        })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
       .style("font-size", "16px")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
     }



  /*
   if(small===0)
    {
        nodeEnter.attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
              .attr("font-size", "11px")
              .attr("fill","black")
    }               
    else
    {
        nodeEnter.attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
              .attr("font-size", "19px")
              .attr("fill","black")
    }
*/

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  var nodeUpdate_hist = node_hist
            .attr("class", function(d,i) { 
                    var ret="hist";
                    if(d.children!= null)
                    {
                        ret="temporary";
                    }                   
                    return ret;
            }) 
      .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("cx",function(d) { 
                    return w_start;
                  })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { 
                    return  d.x;
            })



         vis.selectAll(".temporary").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("cx",function(d) { 
                    return source.y;//w_start;
                  })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { 
                    return  source.x;
            })
      .remove();

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 
        function(d) { 
                    var ret=4.5;
                    if(d.depth==0)
                    {
                        ret=1e-6;
                    }
                    return ret;
            })

      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

var node_histExit=node_hist.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("cx",function(d) { 
                    return source.y;//w_start;
                  })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { 
                    return  source.x;
            })
      .remove();


  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
           .style("opacity",  function(d) { 
                    var ret=1;
                    if(d.source.depth==0)
                    {
                        ret=0;
                    }
                    return ret;
            })
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
       return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
    .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);



//
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
      var datasetq3 = [ 500];
  vis.selectAll("tt").data(datasetq3).enter().append("circle") 
      .attr("r",20)
      .attr("cx",150)
      .attr("cy",150);
*/









  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}    


  //   datasetpp.children.forEach(toggleAll);

 //     toggle(datasetpp.children[2]);

  //    toggle(datasetpp.children[1].children[2]);

      update(datasetpp);     
      var ret=number_of_leaf(datasetpp);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```